# Newsletter input email only refresh page when submit

Tags: campaignmonitor, newsletter

I am using campaign monitor on a expressionengine website. I copy/paste my code from campaign monitor in my footer. There's only a input for my e-mail field and another input to submit. The problem I am facing right now is that when I click on submit the page only refresh. It doesn't go where the action parameter of my form tag

```
<form action="..." method="post">
<p>
    <label for="fieldEmail">Email</label><br />
    <input id="fieldEmail" name="cm-ituykik-ituykik" type="email" required />
</p>
<p>
    <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</p>
```

To be 100% sure that the problem was my code, I tried to link a mailchimp's newsletter and it did the same thing. When I click on submit, the page only refresh and nothing happens.

ExpressionEngine version : 2.5.3

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to close the form tag.

```
</form>
```